# Testing Jackson YAML serialization in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jackson, yaml

In a Spring Boot application I have a method were I serialize a class into YAML using Jackson, then I'm performing some further operations.

```
public void someMethod(SomeClass objectToSerialize) {
   var serialized = yamlMapper.writeValueAsBytes(objectToSerialize);
   //more code
}
```

yamlMapper is an ObjectMapper bean being created in @Configuration class.

I'm wondering what is the best way to test the serialization.
I can mock the yamlMapper to test the rest of the method code, but I would also like to have a test that verifies that the class is being serialized properly, i.e. all my custom mapping settings are not changed and the result is as expected (e.g. order of fields is preserved).

There is @JsonTest that can be used for Jackson serialization testing, but that seems to work only for JSON serialization, not YAML.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a given `objectToSerialize` and know what the serialized output should look like...  Just assert away.  Not mocking or special support classes needed.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud I'm not sure what you mean with 'assert away'. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Tests usually involve some sort of assertion.  Typically that some output equals what's expected. Serialized YAML is text.  You might simply compare strings.  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud Thanks, I basically wasn't sure what the expression 'assert away' means.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud If you want you can write an answer based on your comment as that's the approach I took in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Test with mock!

```
  import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
    
    @SpringBootTest
    class MyMethodTest {
    
        @Mock
        private ObjectMapper mockYamlMapper;
    
        @InjectMocks
        private YourService yourService; // Assume that someMethod() is in this service class
    
        @Test
        void testSomeMethod() throws Exception {
// better if you mock your object with real data here create a method to get //the object
            SomeClass mockObject = mock(SomeClass.class);
            doReturn("mock_serialized_string").when(mockYamlMapper).writeValueAsBytes(mockObject);
    
            yourService.someMethod(mockObject);
    
            // further verification of your method logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question it's not what I'm looking for. That's mocking the actual serialization code, so it tests everything, but the serialization.